# angular 2 router.navigate doesn't work with electron IPC callback

Tags: angular, electron

I am developing and angular 2 application with electron. Here's what i am trying to do.
I have a next button in html 
`<button (click) = nextButtonClickedHandler()>`

the `nextButtonClickedHandler` is described as follows:

```
public nextButtonClickedHandler() {
  this.requestElectronMainProccess(this.afterResponseReceived);
}

private public afterResponseReceived() {
  this._router.navigate(['/next', 'route']);
}

public requestElectronMainProccess(callbackFn: Function) {
  this._electronService.send('request', 'some data');
  this._electronService.once('response', callbackFn);
}
```

So, here, the event log on the console after `_router.navigate` says

1. RoutesRecognised
2. Guards Check Begin
3. Guards Check Successful
4. Guards Check End
5. Navigation End

I also added a console statement to see what the promise is returning.

```
this._router.navigate(['/next', 'route']).then(
 success => console.log('navigation success');
 failure => console.log('navigation end');
);
```

it prints "Navigation success". But, the component does't load. Not sure what is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: this doesnt happen if electron is not involved. for example the below code works perfectly fine

```
public nextButtonClickedHandler() {
  this._router.navigate(['/next', 'route']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled in the same trouble, but with the "dialog" APIs. I noticed this happens not only with Electron APIs, but also with Node.js APIs; in general calling a route function inside a callback raise the issue.

I noticed also that if inside the callback some data of the Angular component are changed, the interface is not updated; I had to make an explicit call to the change detector: `this.changeDetector.detectChanges();`
I remember similar problems in AngularJS, when the `apply()` function has to be called if some work was done "outside" the Angular boundaries; maybe the issues are related.

In my case I was able to circumnvent the problem by switching to the "syncronous" version of `Electron.remote.dialog`, instead of:

```
this.electronService.remote.dialog.showOpenDialog({title:'Output Folder',  
properties: ["openDirectory"] },  (folders) => {
     this.projectService.theProject.targetFolder = folders[0];
     this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/open');
});
```

I tried this:

```
  var folders = this.electronService.remote.dialog.showOpenDialog({title:'Output Folder', 
         properties: ["openDirectory"] });
  if (folders) {
    this.projectService.theProject.targetFolder = folders[0];
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/open');
  }
```

Not only it works in my case (Windows 8 /10), but I can also get rid of the change detector update.

Hope this helps.

PS: I used [ngx-electron](https://thorsten-hans.com/integrating-angular-and-electron-using-ngx-electron-9c36affca25e) to wrap the Electron APIs

Answer (score 6):

workaround...

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private zone: NgZone, private router: Router){
  ipcRenderer.on('youevent', (event) => 
     this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate([path]))
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a bug ticket in electron's github repository.
=> https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11809

I have the same problem.